# It is possible to add to Unordered List during runtime

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a simple HTML page with an Unordered list.  Is it possible to have an input field where you could add more to the list and it would be saved after you submitted it.   What I would like to add would be the content inside of an `<li>` tag as well as the `<li>` tags themselves.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes you can, try with jquery and ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle with a demo of what I think you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/mvJNq/25/

Note that I can not answer as to how you should do this on the server, as that depends on how your serverside code, database etc is set up. However, if all you want is to display it as HTML and not have it saved as the user navigates away, you won't need the Submit button at all - then you just need the "Add" functionality.

Comment: yes, this is basically what i am trying to do, is there any relativly painless way to save what has been added to the page tho? I dont care if it saves straight to the html source im just trying to figure something out.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I just said is hard to give help with unless we know your underlying server structure. But in general - persisting user changes permanently is never painless, not even relatively. Are you using PHP with this? Or just HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: I know, but im just working with HTML css and javascript for now was just wondering if it was possible to add to the code on the page.

Comment: What I have shown in my fiddle example does exactly that. It *adds elements* to the HTML of the page. However, it doesn't *persist* them - so when the page reloads all those changes are gone. There's a big difference there. And that sort of persistance is not doable with just client side code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). You need to do this serverside.

Comment: Do you know if it is even possible to persist elements using HTML JS and css? Because I could definetly see that getting slightly messy.

Comment: It's not that easy to give you a definitive answer. You can use JavaScript on the server too (http://nodejs.org) but it's a completely different *application* of the same language. And you rarely persist the HTML itself, you only persist the data needed to render the HTML at a later stage. This is really a big discussion and not fit for these comments, though.

Comment: I know its kindof a strange thing to ask I was just curious if it was possible bascially without the use of javascript onto the server to store as records.  I understand what you're saying though.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible.

The complexity of this comes in when you want to "save" the items. If the user leaves the page and comes back later will that data be available? If so, you will need a database like mySQL or similar. The li tags can be stored as well, but why?

If you just need that information available in that session you can store in a JavaScript variable and have it loop through the variable and spit them out as `<li>`'s

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Yes i would like it to be saved to the html, just the same as if i had gone into the source and added another `li`. As for why, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - no, it will not be pretty. Here is what you would do:

1. create your base form with any default list items/inputs
2. use jQuery/JavaScript to bind an event handler to a button that you click when you want to add another item (alternatively, you could skip this step and just have another item appear by default)
3. on your event (be it checking that all input boxes have user-entered text, or the click event in step two) add another list item using jQuery.append(...)
4. ensure that you have a hidden input field to be used as a "counter" to keep track of the total number of list items and increment the value of this counter each time you add a new list item (note: you may need to use the ParseInt() method, depending on how you design the code for this field)
5. the page that is receiving the form's inputs should first read the hidden field so that it knows how many items to add, and then you should loop through the items (for or while loop) to add them correctly

Note: I don't know what Server-Side language you are using to handle receiving the form so step 5 is a fairly generic and universally viable option

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to use an add button instead of submit:

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    var savedContent = $('#input').val();
}
```

To create + insert the `<li>`you can use javascript to create the element and append it to the ul.  If you have more than one ul change the index:

```
var content = document.createElement('li');
content.innerText = savedContent;
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(content);
```